# returning content from python web scrape

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to write a script that will allow the user to input a url for a news article. Then it will read that url and scrape it for basic information. I'd like to be able to quickly grab the title, author, and the content of the article itself. Then dump it into a text document.

The issue I have been having is that there seems to be a ton of different ways to do this and since I'm new to python, I thought the community may have some insight into the best ways to approach this problem. Thanks for any comments or direction.

Update* It seems the core issue here is scraping the correct data. What I need is to be able to scrape paragraphs from news websites determined by user input. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to, use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). This is generally agreed to be the most straightforward way of parsing HTML in Python.

Comment: I have been messing with Beautiful Soup but was having trouble getting it to cooperate. I will take a closer look at the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup is one of the most widely used webscraping libraries, especially for quick tasks like this.  Here's how it would look:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://yahoo.com').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# The page's title without html tags
soup.title.string
```

Finding specific items on the page, like an article's author, will depend on the html structure, but it will likely rely on looking for specific css tags:

```
soup.find(id="author")
```

Here's a more specific example.  Say you were looking at a bunch of articles from SFGate like this: http://blog.sfgate.com/energy/2014/02/07/tesla-driver-blames-fatal-crash-on-new-car-smell/

If you look through the source, you'll notice that the article title is an `<h1>` element of class `blogtitle`, and the author's name is a link inside a `<span>` of class `post-author`.  That would equate to the following code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://blog.sfgate.com/energy/2014/02/07/tesla-driver-blames-fatal-crash-on-new-car-smell/').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

## Title ##
# Find the first h1 tag of class 'blogtitle'
title = soup.find("h1", "blogtitle")
# Print out just the string
print(title.string)

## Author ##
# Find the first span of class 'post-author'
author_container = soup.find("span", "post-author")
# Search inside that span for the first link
author = author_container.find("a").string
print(author)
```

As you can see from that example, you will need to customize the code to fit the particular structure of each webpage, and thus it can be very fragile.  See the [Beautiful Soup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) for all the gory details.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I'll mess with this a bit more and see what I come up with